# Segmentation fault (core dumped) c

Tags: uri

## URI 1463

Estou resolvendo o Exercício 1464 do URI ([Link do Exercício](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1463)), e tive o problema de "**segmentation fault (core dumped)**" e não consigo localizar a raíz do erro (sei que propriamente possa estar no `realloc/malloc`).

Segue abaixo o seguinte código do 1463 em cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

typedef struct no
{
    char info;
    struct no *left;
    struct no *right;
} Node;

typedef struct treeBin
{
    Node *root;
} treeBin;

string removeSpace(string input)
{
    string phrase;
    int cont, aux = 0;
    for (cont = 0; cont < input.length(); cont++)
    {
        if (input[cont] != ' ')
        {
            phrase.push_back(input[cont]);
        }
    }
    return phrase;
}

Node *createNode(string input, int first, int end)
{
    int cont = 0, cont_parent = 0, separator = 0;
    char carac = ' ';
    Node *node = (Node *)realloc(node, sizeof(Node));
    if (first == end)
    {
        node->right = NULL;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->info = input[first];
    }
    else
    {
        if ((input[first] == '(') && (input[end] == ')'))
        {
            node = createNode(input, first + 1, end - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            for (cont = first; cont <= end; cont++)
            {
                if (input[cont] == '(')
                {
                    cont_parent++;
                }
                else if (input[cont] == ')')
                {
                    cont_parent--;
                }
                else if (input[cont] == '+' || input[cont] == '-')
                {
                    if (cont_parent == 0)
                    {
                        separator = cont;
                        carac = input[cont];
                    }
                }
                else if (input[cont] == '/' || input[cont] == '*')
                {
                    if (cont_parent == 0 && (carac != '+' && carac != '-'))
                    {
                        separator = cont;
                        carac = input[cont];
                    }
                }
            }
            node->info = carac;
            node->left = createNode(input, first, separator - 1);
            node->right = createNode(input, separator + 1, end);
        }
    }
    return node;
}

void printLine(queue<Node *> row, int currentLevel)
{
    queue<Node *> aux;
    if (row.empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Nivel " << currentLevel << ": ";
        while (!row.empty())
        {
            cout << row.front()->info;
            if (row.front()->left != NULL)
            {
                aux.push(row.front()->left);
            }
            if (row.front()->right != NULL)
            {
                aux.push(row.front()->right);
            }
            row.pop();
        }
        cout << endl;
        printLine(aux, currentLevel + 1);
    }
}

void printTree(treeBin *binTree)
{
    queue<Node *> aux;
    aux.push(binTree->root);
    printLine(aux, 0);
}

main()
{
    string input;
    treeBin *binTree = new treeBin;

    getline(cin, input);
    do
    {
        input = removeSpace(input);
        cout << input << endl;
        binTree->root = createNode(input, 0, input.length() - 1);
        printTree(binTree);
        getline(cin, input);
        if (!cin.eof())
            cout << endl;
    } while (!cin.eof());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Temos que entender que segmentation fault (core dumped) é um erro muito comum e dificil em tempo de execução, naturalmente todo programa é chamado de processo esse processo tem uma parte da memoria destinada para ele que é gerenciado pelo SO sistema operacional.

O que ocorre quando segmentation fault acontece é que seu PROCESSO ou seja seu programa está acessando a memoria de outro processo, como por exemplo quando acessamos um ponteiro NULL.

Eu dividi a solução em 3 etapas, 1: compilar a versão de debug, 2: usar o gdb para debugar.

1:`g++ -g main.c -o main`

a FLAG -g indica a versão de debug.

2:  `gdb main`

Primeiro lancei um break em main avancei linha por linha, avançando percebi que seu codigo deu problema na seguinte linha:

133: binTree->root = createNode(input, 0, input.length() - 1);

Entrando na função eu notei a seguinte linha:

36:    `Node *node = (Node *)realloc(node, sizeof(Node));`

Note que realloc só funciona para um ponteiro que já tenha sido alocado, tanto por new quanto por malloc ou calloc.

Corrigi sua linha por:    `Node *node = new Node; // Alocando a memoria.`

CODIGO CORRIGIDO:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

typedef struct no
{
    char info;
    struct no *left;
    struct no *right;
} Node;

typedef struct treeBin
{
    Node *root;
} treeBin;

string removeSpace(string input)
{
    string phrase;
    int cont, aux = 0;
    for (cont = 0; cont < input.length(); cont++)
    {
        if (input[cont] != ' ')
        {
            phrase.push_back(input[cont]);
        }
    }
    return phrase;
}

Node *createNode(string input, int first, int end)
{
    int cont = 0, cont_parent = 0, separator = 0;
    char carac = ' ';
    Node *node = new Node; // CORRIGIDO
    // Node *node = (Node *)realloc(node, sizeof(Node)); ERRO
    if (first == end)
    {
        node->right = NULL;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->info = input[first];
    }
    else
    {
        if ((input[first] == '(') && (input[end] == ')'))
        {
            node = createNode(input, first + 1, end - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            for (cont = first; cont <= end; cont++)
            {
                if (input[cont] == '(')
                {
                    cont_parent++;
                }
                else if (input[cont] == ')')
                {
                    cont_parent--;
                }
                else if (input[cont] == '+' || input[cont] == '-')
                {
                    if (cont_parent == 0)
                    {
                        separator = cont;
                        carac = input[cont];
                    }
                }
                else if (input[cont] == '/' || input[cont] == '*')
                {
                    if (cont_parent == 0 && (carac != '+' && carac != '-'))
                    {
                        separator = cont;
                        carac = input[cont];
                    }
                }
            }
            node->info = carac;
            node->left = createNode(input, first, separator - 1);
            node->right = createNode(input, separator + 1, end);
        }
    }
    return node;
}

void printLine(queue<Node *> row, int currentLevel)
{
    queue<Node *> aux;
    if (row.empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Nivel " << currentLevel << ": ";
        while (!row.empty())
        {
            cout << row.front()->info;
            if (row.front()->left != NULL)
            {
                aux.push(row.front()->left);
            }
            if (row.front()->right != NULL)
            {
                aux.push(row.front()->right);
            }
            row.pop();
        }
        cout << endl;
        printLine(aux, currentLevel + 1);
    }
}

void printTree(treeBin *binTree)
{
    queue<Node *> aux;
    aux.push(binTree->root);
    printLine(aux, 0);
}

main()
{
    string input;
    treeBin *binTree = new treeBin;

    getline(cin, input);
    do
    {
        input = removeSpace(input);
        cout << input << endl;
        binTree->root = createNode(input, 0, input.length() - 1);
        printTree(binTree);
        getline(cin, input);
        if (!cin.eof())
            cout << endl;
    } while (!cin.eof());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado William, porém continua apresentando Segmentation Fault no Debugger e no URI, (na mesma linha `Node *node = new Node;`)

Comment: Estranho, o código funciona no g++ 8.1.0. com certeza tem algo haver com a versão do compilador usado.